# intel realsense get depth image values

Tags: c#, realsense

I am trying to put all the info depth values of a frame into a 2D array.
My problem that the pointer p points to a null value and not to the data stored in memory. if the sample.depth != null an image should be stored in the memory(correct me if I'm wrong).
I searched for examples and found this [example](http://mtaulty.com/CommunityServer/blogs/mike_taultys_blog/archive/2015/04/15/intel-realsense-camera-f200-a-bit-of-depth.aspx) but still I have the same null problem.

```
 if (sample.depth != null)
        {
            for (int y = 0; y < sample.depth.info.height; y++)
            {
                unsafe
                {
                    UInt16* p = (UInt16*)dataDepth.planes[0].ToPointer();
                    for (int x = 0; x < sample.depth.info.width; x++)
                    {
                        picDepth[y, x] = p[0];
                        p++;
                    }
                }
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

You're calling sample.depth.AcquireAccess with dataDepth somewhere around, right?

Comment: 'p' is an object and that wasn't Initialized... yup didn't see that